# Notify a person that they have/need to create an account on Django site

Tags: python, django

I'm working with an event entry system whereby a user (`Client`) will be able to create x amount of users (`Entrant`) for an event, so both `Client` and `Entrant` relate to the `User` model.

A client would create an entrant by entering an email address which would then send an email to that person to tell them they have an account. Our initial thought is to create the user and email them a password, and instruct them to change their password.

I personally don't like the idea of this but don't know a 'best practise' approach as I've never encountered automated user creation before.

I like the idea of that when the email is sent, there is an `Entrant` table with a record of the person's email address and they are sent a link to the site which takes them to a form where they create their own `User` account and this ties in to the `Entrant` model.

Although this may lead to duplication of an email address in the `Entrant` and then the `User` unless `Entrant` didn't store the email address and the email was sent with an ID ref to `Entrant`. Then all data could be saved when the `User` is created and tied up to the `Entrant`.

I'm having trouble finding articles/SA questions on this so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Let the Client add the email, send an email with a Django generated password (secure) and add an activation link so that the user needs to verify the account and activate through a token.
This is all available in the implementation of the django.contrib.auth module and the code is provided there. password, token generation and emailing / activation are also provided in it as reusable functions.

Comment: Thanks, that felt like a bit of a stupid question due to the nature of it, but equally I don't have anywhere else to ask. I should of known standard Auth would be sufficient. Currently reading about custom user models so I'll stick with this.

Comment: I don't feel it was a stupid question, so no need to apologize :)